# What is this dark copper-less PCB feature?

Tags: pcb-design, identification

Excuse the title, I'm not even sure what to call it, as far as I can tell it isn't a component but a copper-less layer of PCB showing?

[image: Screenshot from EEVBlog #271]

It's on a 'Zoom H1' microphone/recorder's PCB, as seen in [EEVBlog #271 - Zoom H1 Recorder teardown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CCWnJ35obQ&t=1374). (As far as I noticed it didn't get a mention in the video.)

Comment: It does if that's what it is? But I've never seen one look like this, all dark and at two depths (by the look of it?).

Comment: Ah! I stared at the pattern some more, I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: It is a button like those described in that other question - no doubt about it. The silkscreen is a little unclear in your pic, but it doesn't take too much imagination to see it as "SW1" - aka Switch 1.